# iOS Animation: don't block the GUI while animating a not pre-known animation

Tags: ios, multithreading, animation, user-interface

I am animating an image and do not know the next image ahead of time. I'd like the GUI to remain responsive through this.

At each animation step (~800ms), I've tried to calculate the needed image through `block` and then updating the UI through `uiBlock`.

Using GCD, at each animation step I run the following function with `block` as my long task and `uiBlock` containing the code to refresh the GUI:

```
-(void)runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block withUIblock:(dispatch_block_t)uiBlock onThread:(NSString *)thread{
    if ([thread isEqualToString:@"main"]) {
        [block invoke];
        [uiBlock invoke];
    } else if ([thread isEqualToString:@"background"]){

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
            [block invoke];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [uiBlock invoke];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This block of code needs to run like so:

```
for (i=0; i<iterations; i++){
    [block invoke];
    [uiBlock invoke]; // because we want to see the result after each iteration
}
```

I've used `sync` and not `async` precisely because each `block` has to be run before the next animations step `block` can be run; the seconds `block` needs the first `block`.

Most of the tutorials I've seen online seem to show obviously parallel tasks such as pulling data from a URL. I'm wondering how to have my UI responsive while using `dispatch_sync` (as that seems to be a requirement).

Answer (score 0):

try by changing your code to->

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
            [block invoke]; //make sure that this is synchronous.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [uiBlock invoke];
            });
        });
```

I guess `[block invoke]` will download the image, then make in synchronous download .
like `[NSData dataWithUrl:url]`.

so, the thread's `PC` (program counter) still points to that block's download instruction until the download is finished.
`dispatch_async ([uiBlock invoke])` won't be executed until the download finishes.
 After download finishes it executes `[uiBlock]`.

Comment: I've updated my question; I need this to run iteratively. Your solution works in a sense. It runs `[uiBlock invoke]` in random order. It needs to update after each `[block invoke]`.

Comment: ok. are you running this animation onetime or you loop the animation many times.

Comment: And, suppose you made the request for firstImage,then you wait for .8secs and will you now make a request for second image? what if the firstImage didn't downloaded in .8secs but downloaded after 3secs but second image downloaded at 2secs,will you still display the first image or continue from secongImage?

Comment: If you explain above, i might help you solve the issue.

Comment: It's a one-time animation. I have an image and do some advanced signal processing jazz to calculate a new image (from the old image!) and show that.